# Replacing multiple instances of a symbol with different variables and assignments

Tags: replacement, assignment

I have an expression of the form:

```
expr=x+y+n+Sin[n]+n^2
```

I would like to replace each of the variables `n` with a different variable, like:

```
x+y+n1+Sin[n2]+n3^2
```

The order doesn't matter, but it matters that each `n` have a different name.

I can find the positions of the `n`'s simply with:

```
pos=Position[expr,n]
```

and this returns a list of positions `{{1}, {2, 1}, {5, 1}}` as expected. I would then like to run through this list and make replacements in those positions. However, I don't want to have to do this by hand. Clearly I could do:

```
expr[[5,1]]=n3
```

but the real expression I have is many thousands of times larger.

I have tried using:

```
Apply[Part, Join[{expr}, pos[[3]]]]=n2
```

which would allow be to do this in a loop, or functionally, but this doesn't alter the element of the expression as I would like. I have tried playing with `Hold` in various places but it doesn't seem to work.

Anything simple that I am missing?

Comment: `expr /. n :> Unique@n`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That's done the trick.

Comment: expr = x + y + n + Sin[n] + n^2;
j = 0;
expr /. n :> (j++; nn[j])

Comment: (Beaten once again by that "@belisarius 1 min ago" character.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau the reason is that procedural code gets a penalty :D  HNY BTW

Comment: @Yves Klett I meant "beaten" in terms of "first to appear". But I agree his is the better method. Not faulting mine specifically for procedural usage but more because it has an unscoped global.

Comment: @belisarius answer, answer, ANSWER!

Comment: @YvesKlett Done :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may do something like:

```
expr = x + y + n + Sin[n] + n^2; 
{newExpr, {newVars}} = Reap[expr /. n :> Sow[Unique@n]];
{newExpr, newVars}
(*
 {n$9881 + n$9882^2 + x + y + Sin[n$9883], {n$9881, n$9882, n$9883}}
*)
```

Comment: Hey, but that thing is worth lots of $!

Comment: @Yves Use `Unique["n"]` to fix that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Why do you want to fix that? Don't you like "$"?

Comment: Yves complained about "$" so I gave a solution.  Also `Unique["n"]` gives results that match the OP's example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Damn, my understanding was that Yves was trying to buy my answer.

Comment: Okay, I suppose he wasn't "complaining" -- I took it as a humorous way to point out the $xxxx extensions in your answer, when the OP used simply `n1`,`n2`,`n3`.  Anyway, you already have my vote. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard verily, ´twas penned in high spirits - but your comment in fact taught me a new trick :D